# Alinhar DIV de type=text

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estou a tentar alinhar a minha caixa de texto da newsletter com o texto de cima e não estou a conseguir, será que me pode ajudar?? 
[image: Meu footer newsletter]

O site em questão é este 41jeep.com/OC2

Comment: Copie o trecho de código relevante pra cá em vez de por o link criando um [MCVE] que reproduza o problema, pra não correr o risco de ser marcado como spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Experimenta o `margin-left: 0;` para a tua div `.newsletter_block .form-control` no css.

Deves ter algo no fim como:

```
.newsletter_block .form-control {
    background: #363636;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    color: #949595;
    height: 36px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Contudo se esta margem for importante, podes adicionar uma nova class, por exemplo: **no-margin-left** e dizer no css que essa class em específico não tem margem à esquerda.

Este problema aconteceu porque estás a usar margin-left: 10px por defeito para todos os inputs de texto.

Espero ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu vou responder porque o problema é simples, mas, por favor, acostume-se a **sempre** criar [um exemplo, mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e não apontar apenas o link para o seu site.

---

Todos os `inputs[type="text"]` estão com margem a esquerda de 5 pixels.

Você pode solucionar isso criando uma classe nova com `margin-left: 0` e aplicar esta classe no seu input.